# Issues counting column of numbers in numpy array

Tags: python

I have a situation where I know the last number of a column (number six) in a pandas df series, and now I can find the number before it. But I wanted a count of the second number over 3600 lines of the column which I name as 'd1'. I can generate the output column, which I then try to convert into an array. But generating count values from the output column produces only one number and only one occurrence...the last number of the original pandas column. Please look at the code and see where I went wrong.Obviously there is a simpler way to count the second last number, but I don't know another way. Thanks.

```
for df1['d1'].iloc[-2] in y:  # y is the pandas dataframe series
    if df1['d1'].iloc[-2] < df1['d1'].iloc[-1]:  # checks to see if less than last number
        print(df1['d1'].iloc[-2])  # this prints a column of all numbers less than last one
print(type(df1['d1'].iloc[-2]))  # describes output as numpy integers
a = df1['d1'].iloc[-2]  # Here attempt at converting to numpy array
b = np.asarray(a)
unique_elements, counts_elements = np.unique(b, return_counts=True)  # count the output column
print(np.asarray((unique_elements, counts_elements)))
print(type(b))  # but shows it is an array
print(b)  # does not print out as array`enter code here`
```

Output is here with last few values shown on output of for loop.

```
2
4
2
1
1
3
2
2
5
3
2
2
<class 'numpy.int64'>
[[6]
 [1]]
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
6

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: what do you want to achieve? please provide input data and expected output

Comment: df1['d1'].iloc[-2] is the code that generates the output. I want to achieve a count of the column of numbers show. The input data is that column and the expected output for example two would be 6 counts for number 2, two counts for number 3. Taken from last few values I have shown.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps following example might help you.

```
import collections
from collections import Counter

x = [1, 2, 3, 1]
c = Counter(x)

print(c.most_common())
print(c[1])
```

you'll get the following output:

```
[(1, 2), (2, 1), (3, 1)]
2
```

Comment: Thank you Marina, however the column of my numbers shown is type <class 'numpy.int64'>. This is a 'raw' column of numbers. You have shown x as an array already. My big problem is how to convert my 'raw' numpy column into an array and use your code above. If you can show me how to covert into an array like you have (x) then that would be a big help. Thanks

Comment: If you want to change a data type of some iterable data structure you can do following: `x_conv = [np.int32(item) for item in x]`. In you case I suppose you want to make it `int(item)`.

Comment: Marina, I don't quite follow. Am I missing something? The code  that I have written is given variable 'a', a = df1['d1'].iloc[-2] . This will print the column of numbers I talk about on left side column. But using the numpy.int64 how to use 'a' correctly since a_conv = [np.int64(a) for a in a?] . I understand the formula you gave, but I am missing a key variable to convert my column (a) to an array.

Comment: If you want a list of elements less than the last element in the column try this `x = [df['d1'][item] for item in range(0,len(df)) if df['d1'][item] < df['d1'].tolist()[-1]]`

Comment: [1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1,]
<class 'list'>    This is a shortened version of the list according to the code you gave me above. This is an excellent start as now I can count  the elements since they are in a numpy list. A good ending Marina.